# How do I export Fogbugz items to TFS 2012 work items?

Tags: tfs, fogbugz, fogbugz-on-demand

I have a list of project and bug items in fogbugz.  I would like to export them into TFS instead of using the VS Fogzbug tool. Is there a tool available to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TFS Integration Platform, and write an adapter for Fogbugz, but that is an expensive solution. The benefit of this solution is that you keep the history.

Another much cheaper solution is to use the Excel integration in TFS to import the items in TFS.

Comment: What about hierarchies?  Can you specify it in the excel integration?

Comment: Yes you can from 2010 and up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286621.aspx